ESD protection - What circuits need to be proctected?
I have some confusions about ESD and what circuit need to be protected against ESD.
Suppose I have a board in a metallic box. In one case the board is connected to the metallic box and in the other case the board is isolated from the box through a capacitor. The ESD is applied on the box.
The voltage of the ESD can be as high as 15kV (whatever the value it does not really change the problem)
An IC can tolerate a voltage on its pins equal to 80V and 6V5.
Here is my drawing as a summary :

So when the circuit is isolated from the metallic box, it seems relatively simple to protect all the circuits. It is sufficient to add an ESD diode to limit the maximum voltage on the capacitor and the energy going throug the groud. All the rest of the circuit will be level shifted temporary to the ESD voltage level.
However when the "board ground" and "the box ground" are the same, it seems more difficult to protect all the IC pins from ESD. it seems that all the pin will need to have a dedicated ESD pin depending on the working voltage of each pin. Do you agree ?
When I look at this IC for example, even the pin where the supplies voltage is coming seems to need to be protected against ESD :

What is suprising me is that when I look to ESD protection, the working voltage is limted to 24V ? It is so not common to protect higher voltage than 24V ? So I suppose I am going in the wrong way.

So how to protect a circuit from ESD coming from mettalic box ?

Jess - Hi, (a) Is this diagram your own work, or was it copied/adapted from elsewhere? (b) Which website is this image copied from? Please add a link to its source, as required by the site referencing rule. TY

@SamGibson I drawn it. Shoud I precise that it is from my own work ?

Jess - Hi, (a) The author was unclear as you referred to it as "the drawing", not "my drawing". Although your own drawings don't require a reference according to the site rule, it can be difficult for other site members to know whether a drawing is someone's own work or not, if they don't make that clear. Therefore if a drawing/photo/etc. is your own, it can help to be clear and say "my drawing" etc. That should avoid people flagging the post (which causes us mods to get involved :) ) || (b) Please remember to link to the source of the screenshot which I linked. TY

You left important thing out : Is the circuit fully enclosed in the metal box, or does it have connections/ports/etc to outside world, and does it have any buttons/switches/etc which the user can touch and zap a button with ESD?

Following on @Justme question, if it does have connectors to the outside world, do those connectors have ESD diodes on every pin?

TI also has 36 V diodes when you click on the "View all products" link.

The 80 V pin is already protected by the large decoupling capacitor(s). In fact, ESD protection often involves shunting the current spikes into the power supply.

Thank you for all your comments ! Effectively @CL. you re right about the 80V pin !

The best way to think about how ESD can damage a circuit is to consider the current that can flow into the circuit board due to the high voltage discharge. Importantly we are interested in the path that current takes so, if for instance, your circuit board is fully self-contained within the box and has no interconnections that exit the box to other equipment then, the current due to an ESD discharge has nowhere to go and, in fact, barely anything flows and your circuits are largely protected due to almost zero current flow.
On the other hand, if you have (say) an RS232 port (or a connection to an external power supply), you have to recognize that the external connection may be earthed or appear as a low earth impedance to ESD transients and, when that happens, you can have a spike of several amps (short duration of course) flowing through your circuit board from the initial zap to the conducting (but unearthed) case.
That current spike may be moderate (if the case is unconnected to the circuit board) or, it may be several tens of amps if the case connects to the circuit board 0 volts.
It is that current spike that you need to protect sensitive ICs from. This is when you consider using TVS diodes (or capacitors) to act as a bypass path for that several-amp surge. Of course, it's down to the actual circuit how this is implemented.
If your box is always earthed and you apply an ESD discharge to it then there is no worry usually but, some smaller-than-several-amp surge currents can find a path through your circuit board and cause temporary loss of function and performance. Again, the devil is in the detail both circuit-wise, layout, and board position within the enclosure.
So, already we have several initial scenarios and yours will be one of them: -

Circuit and wiring fully contained within the box (connected to box or not)
Circuit with external wiring that can be externally earthed
Circuit with box connection and with external wiring that can be externally earthed
Circuit inside an earthed box

Then you have to also consider "ports" on your enclosure receiving a direct zap from ESD and go through the scenarios listed directly above.

Thank you for your reply, How a current coming from the metallic ground could go into RS232 pins (excluded ground pin ?). It could pass through the transceiver IC and then goes through the next RS232 transceiver and then it will go back to ground ? Is it what you think ?

@Jess re-read my last paragraph

@Jess Someone's fingers poking at a connector would be the most likely reason for that. Usually there's TVS placed on serial bus signals for that reason. And modern transceivers have built-in protection to some degree (in a nasty EMI environment, you wouldn't use RS232 but rugged RS485). The EMI current wouldn't enter the sensitive parts of IC if there are conducting TVS since it takes the path of least resistance. Think of it as EMI always being in a hurry, it has no time to take the scenic route if a quicker route is present :)

In many applications the chassis is tied directly to ground at one single place, usually at the point where the ground pin of the supply is located. And so ESD events will lead to current that take that route. Connecting all metal surfaces to chassis is the standard counter-measure against ESD/EMI.
When doing such a design, we assume that there should be no reason for the spike/EMI current the enter a path through our signal ground of the PCB, as it seeks the shortest path to the supply ground. Then you shouldn't need to protect every IC etc because if the EMI made it there, that means that the EMI current is taking the wrong, harmful route to begin with due to bad grounding.
If that assumption is not good enough, because of very high EMC requirements, we'd use bidirectional TVS as in your picture on every connector: supply, serial buses etc. Then tie the TVS to the shortest path to chassis. Then some filters.
The chassis may in such a scenario (naturally depending on application) not necessarily be tied directly to signal ground inside your particular product, if there are shielded cables and the like attached to the chassis. Then you tie the shield to chassis but leave the signal ground alone. Connecting signal ground to chassis would be done in some strategic location, like on a vehicle: tie battery minus to chassis at a point close to the battery.
